# converting string to sql date the original value gets altered

Tags: java, sql

I have a simple problem while converting String to SQL date.

```
 java.sql.Date sqlDate = getSqlDateFormat("2010-10-10");
```

**Expected to store `2010-10-10` in the `H2 database` but it stores `2009-12-27` instead.**
Any help will be appreciated.

```
public static java.sql.Date getSqlDateFormat(String dateInString)  {
        java.util.Date date = transformFromStringToDate(dateInString);
        return convertUtilDateToSqlDate(date);
    }
```

The method in turn calls `transformFromStringToDate()` to convert the input `String` into `java.util.Date`

```
public static java.util.Date transformFromStringToDate(String dateInString) {
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
  java.util.Date utilDate = dateFormat.parse(dateInString);
  return utilDate;
 }
```

Finally I'm calling the `convertUtilDateToSqlDate()` to store it in the database

```
public static Date convertUtilDateToSqlDate(java.util.Date date)
    {
        Date sqlDate = new Date(date.getTime());
        return sqlDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your format to `yyyy-MM-dd` The year must be lowercase `y` rather than uppercase.

If you see the documentation of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) `Y`is the `Week year`.
`y` is the field `Year`

Comment: Can you explain why `2010-10-10` becomes `2009-12-27`

Comment: Ok ok got it actually it was doing the right conversion only `Y stands - week year` instead in want the `y stands - year`

Comment: what javadoc says - A week year is in sync with a WEEK_OF_YEAR cycle. All weeks between the first and last weeks (inclusive) have the same week year value. Therefore, the first and last days of a week year may have different calendar year values.